# What kind of nonlinear differential equation is this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[nonlinear differential equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a5gV.png)

Is it possible to obtain below result by considering z(0)=0?

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Py6.png)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.